# Spring boot eureka server bean creation error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am not able to run the spring eureka server, I do get the following error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'optionalArgs'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'discoveryClientOptionalArgs' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/config/DiscoveryClientOptionalArgsConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/eventbus/spi/EventBus
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]

Below is the my code which runs in my mac machine perfectly, But the same is not working in my windows machine and was not able to find out the solution for it I reinstalled sts tool suite, eclipse everything still the same error persists

MyApplication.java

```
package com.example.microservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class MicroserviceApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(MicroserviceApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
    port: 8000

eureka:
   client:
       register-with-eureka: false
       fetch-registry: false
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>microservice</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>microservice</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Only in my windows machine it is not working and its throwing the above issue which I have mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error below, your project is missing a jar file

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/netflix/eventbus/spi/EventBus
```

Have you tried by including `netflix-eventbus` jar file in your pom?

Comment: Hey @amdg The issue got solved after I installed the eventBus pom but Now I am unble to start the app, I do get the below error 2017-12-01 16:44:22.925  INFO 13480 --- [           main] c.e.m.MicroserviceApplication            : Started MicroserviceApplication in 7.888 seconds (JVM running for 8.413)
2017-12-01 16:44:24.678 ERROR 13480 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Is your registry running? It will fail otherwise.

Comment: I am running the eureka server itself not the client, so once eureka server is up then only registry problems will occur right if I am not wrong.

Comment: Hey, looks like some problem with your configuration.